# Help to understand: “The apology was not offered to the right,”

Tags: sentence-meaning, terminology, reading-comprehension

> Bee later apologized for “using an expletive” to describe the first 
>   daughter. “It was inappropriate and inexcusable. I crossed a line, and
>   I deeply regret it,” she said.
>
> The wording of the statement was “very
>   specific,” she told The Daily Beast.
>
> **“The apology was not offered to
>   the right,”** she said. “It was not offered as a concession to their
>   demands, at all. It was offered in a very specific manner and I don’t
>   regret putting it out there. I think it was the right thing to do.”

I don't quite understand “*The apology was not offered to the right*,”. What is "*to the right*" referring to?

Also, what does she mean by "offered in a very specific manner"? What kind of a specific manner is it?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/samantha-bee-regrets-1-thing-111629615.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "right" is referring to the [politics definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/right):

> **Right**
>   political parties or people that have traditional opinions, and that believe in low taxes, property, and industry being privately owned, and less help for the poor

It comes from the [Left-Right political spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%E2%80%93right_political_spectrum) and you can visualize it in America like this:

[image]

It's a spectrum (scale, range) so a person's ideas can fall somewhere on the line. If you are reading about politics (especially American), you will often see phrases that come from this, such as "far right", "center", "leaning left", "leftist" to describe the Democrats and Republicans a little more specifically than just grouping them all together on one side or the other.

---

> "The apology was not offered to the right."

This means that she was not saying sorry to the Republicans, who demanded the apology.

> "It was offered in a very specific manner"

The wording of the apology was specifically saying sorry about using an expletive (a curse word). But she does not apologize about thinking that way about Trump's daughter and does not apologize to her specifically. She was really only saying sorry for using the "bad word".

Answer (score 4):

The original post's quote is political.

Starting with the French Revolution, there has been the concept of a ["Left / Right" political spectrum](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/Left%E2%80%93right_politics).  At the beginning of the French Revolution, the aristocratic and clerical members of the French legislature sat on the right-hand side of the legislative chamber.  These members were the most willing to maintain the existing order.  The commoners sat on the left.  These members were most willing to change the existing order.

In the United States today, former President Obama, former Secretary of State Hillary Clinton, Samantha Bee, and *The Daily Beast* are on the "left" of the political spectrum.  They support a wide category of social changes, and support a number of government policy changes that would increase the power of the federal government.

President Trump and his most vocal supporters are on the "right" of the political spectrum.  The support a different set of social changes, and propose various reductions in the power of the federal government.